# C#: MWArray and Getting an Instance of Class

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, matlab-compiler

Using MATLAB Compiler Runtime (mcr) i have created dll of the entropy.m choosing FrameWork version 4.0. I have added this dll to c# references. Also i have to add MWArray.dll to create the needed paramters for methods.

```
        >     public class Entropy : IDisposable
        >      {
        >          //Constructors,Finalize,Methods,Class Members are located here.
        >      }
        >      using com.Entropy;
        >      using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays;
        >      using MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility;
```

Here is my problem. I am trying to get an instance of Entropy class like

```
 Entropy ep = new Entroyp();
```

However it throws an exception that says:

```
> The type initializer for 'com.Enthropy.Enthropy threw an exception.
```

Also while i try to create an `MWNumericArray` it throws the same exception. I've tried to change framework version of my project to 4.0 but it did not work. What is the reason of this error?

In addition i've looked at links below.

[ACCESSING MATLAB FUNCTIONS FROM C#.NET](http://domoreinlesstime.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/access-matlab-from-c/)

[Using MATLAB Builder NE](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/using-matlab-builder-ne-68758.html)

[Is there an example of using the "MWArray" data type in a .NET language such as C# with a MATLAB Builder for .NET component?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3NL1YX/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Okay. After installing the MCR, i have done everything at the beginning. Created the dll of entropy.m. Then i opened an earlier version of my project, i mean i deleted the added references; `MWArray.dll` and Entropy.dll. After that i have added those references to my project back. Now it works fine.

The important points:
1)Before create a dll file of any MatLab function **INSTALL MCR**.
2)While creating dll try to give different names to class and project. I mean if you create project that name is `Entropy.prj` dont create your class name as `Entropy`.
3)Don't forget to add `MWArray.dll` to your project. Its location is

> (..//Program Files(x86)//MATLAB\MATLAB CompilerRuntime\v81\toolbox\dotnetbuilder\bin\win32\v2.0)